# JSON Parsing - Python code is throwing error

Tags: python-3.x

```
{"resourcePermission": [
        {
            "organization": "tubro",
            "path": "/",
            "permissions": [
                "get"
            ]
        },
        {
            "organization": "tubro",
            "path": "/applications",
            "permissions": [
                "get"
            ]
        },
        {
            "organization": "tubro",
            "path": "/apiproducts",
            "permissions": [
                "put",
                "get",
                "delete"
            ]
        },
        {
            "organization": "tubro",
            "path": "/developers",
            "permissions": [
                "put",
                "get",
                "delete"
            ]
        },
        etc ..,
```

I need to capture "permissions" in a variable so that I can use it elsewhere as k[0] = put, k[1] = get, k[2] = delete. 
But my code below is not working.

```
role_data = json.loads(response1.text)
role_list_json = list(role_data.values())[0]
num_role=len(role_list_json)
    k = 0
    while k < 1:
        col = 2
        test = role_list_json["permissions"]["k"]
        worksheet.write(row, col, test)
        k += 1
        col += 1
```

I am getting the below error:

```
test = role_list_json["permissions"]["k"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you made it a list via `role_list_json = list(role_data.values())[0]` so to access the elements you need to specify the index number

**EDIT:**

**Well, in addition to the below, partially because I have no idea what I'm looking at at, my first comment is, whoever provided you with that code, needs to use descriptive variables, and two, that code cannot possibly run. I edited some things and took some liberties so you can see the output but I must stress THIS IS REALLY REALLLLLLLLYYYYY BAD CODE. BTW I removed `k` because it didn't even show up as a reference at this line `worksheet.write(row, col, test)`:**

```
>>> role_data = {"resourcePermission": [ { "organization": "tubro", "path": "/", "permissions": [ "get" ] }, { "organization": "tubro", "path": "/applications", "permissions": [ "get" ] }, { "organization": "tubro", "path": "/apiproducts", "permissions": [ "put", "get", "delete" ] }, { "organization": "tubro", "path": "/developers", "permissions": [ "put", "get", "delete" ] }, { "organization": "tubro", "path": "/apps", "permissions": [ "put", "get", "delete" ] }, { "organization": "tubro", "path": "/companies", "permissions": [ "put", "get", "delete" ] } ] }


>>> role_list_json = list(role_data.values())[0]


>>> num_role=len(role_list_json)

#THIS IS HORRIBLE CODE DONE THIS WAY SO YOU CAN SEE
>>> while row <= num_role:
        col = 0
        while col <= 3:
            try:
                test = role_list_json[row]["permissions"][col]
                print(row, col, test)
                col += 1
            except:
                row += 1
                col = 4



#OUTPUT
(0, 0, 'get')
(1, 0, 'get')
(2, 0, 'put')
(2, 1, 'get')
(2, 2, 'delete')
(3, 0, 'put')
(3, 1, 'get')
(3, 2, 'delete')
(4, 0, 'put')
(4, 1, 'get')
(4, 2, 'delete')
(5, 0, 'put')
(5, 1, 'get')
(5, 2, 'delete')  








#BETTER CODE
>>> for i in range(len(role_list_json)):
        for ii in range(len(role_list_json[i]["permissions"])):
            print(i, ii, role_list_json[i]["permissions"][ii])


#OUTPUT
(0, 0, 'get')
(1, 0, 'get')
(2, 0, 'put')
(2, 1, 'get')
(2, 2, 'delete')
(3, 0, 'put')
(3, 1, 'get')
(3, 2, 'delete')
(4, 0, 'put')
(4, 1, 'get')
(4, 2, 'delete')
(5, 0, 'put')
(5, 1, 'get')
(5, 2, 'delete')
```

**Original Post**

So to access the elements you need to type something like this using the index `NUMBERS` not string identifiers. So you should rewrite your code knowing this. Basically `[k]` is in the wrong place (it should be before and `["permissions"]`) and should not be a string it should just be `[k]` so that these integers get substituted in:

```
>>> role_list_json[1]["permissions"]
['get']


>>> role_list_json[2]["permissions"]
['put', 'get', 'delete']
```

.

So `test = role_list_json["permissions"]["k"]` should be

.

```
test = role_list_json[k]["permissions"]
```

.

**EDIT:**

.

Why are you using `while k < 1` if you mention k[0], k[1], and k[2], in your original post? I mean, I don't see why you didn't use for loops at the very least? In all honesty, you might even want to rewrite the code because to access the individual elements `put`, `get`, and `delete` you'd even want

```
>>> role_list_json[2]["permissions"][0]
'put'


>>> role_list_json[2]["permissions"][1]
'get'


>>> role_list_json[2]["permissions"][2]
'delete'
```

Comment: Actually it's a part of a bigger script. I have many loops before this one. I am trying to auto-generate an excel sheet from an API which provides JSON data. So, I have to use variable so that I can use this data wherever I want. That's the reason I am doing it this way.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: role_data = json.loads(response1.text)
role_list_json = list(role_data.values())[0]
num_role=len(role_list_json)
     k = 0
        while k < 2:
            col = 2
            permission_name = role_list_json[2]["permissions"][0]
            worksheet.write(row, col, permission_name)
            col += 1
            k += 1                         Giving below error - 
permission_name = role_list_json[2]["permissions"][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I think you may have responded before I edited my response. I know you need to use a variable, but you'l never access the data using a `string` vs. using a `number` so your variable needs to be a `number'. So, honestly it looks like you're pretty new at Python. I'll post something that will help you organize the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = role_list_json["permissions"][k]
```

You looked for the array entry on position `["k"]`. I guess you want the result from your loop index right? So it needs to be `[k]`. Index as string like "k" is not possible.

Comment: Correct. I am sorry for that. But still it's not working -
role_data = json.loads(response1.text) role_list_json = list(role_data.values())[0] num_role=len(role_list_json) k = 0 while k < 2: col = 2 permission_name = role_list_json[2]["permissions"][k] worksheet.write(row, col, permission_name) col += 1 k += 1 Giving below error - permission_name = role_list_json[2]["permissions"][k] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Well you question was about the error `test = role_list_json["permissions"]["k"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` and my answer answers exactly where your issue is.